Is simple random sampling an assumption on the probability measure in the abstract probability measure space?
I am wondering whether my intuition about what simple random sampling means is correct.
Say we have an abstract probability measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$,
some measurable space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, and a map $X$ that is a valid random variable written as $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then, $\mathbb{P}_{X}$ is the pushforward measure of $\mathbb{P}$ induced by $X$, which is a probability measure $\mathbb{P}_{X} : \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0, 1]$. Thus, $\mathbb{P}_{X}$ is the probability distribution measure of $X$, and
$(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mathbb{P}_{X})$ is the concrete probability measure space (i.e., as depicted below).

Is it correct to say that:

The functional form we select for $\mathbb{P}_{X}$ is our assumption about the distribution of the measurement $X$ in the population (i.e., sample space $\Omega$)?

The simple random sampling mechanism (i.e., the uniform distribution) is our assumption about the probabilities of individual $\{\omega\}$ elements (e.g., people) in $\Omega$? In other words, do we assume that $\mathbb{P}$ is the uniform distribution, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\}) = \frac{1}{|\Omega|}$, for a finite population?


My background is in psychology and in my readings, I haven't encountered any author describing simple random sampling in line with my second question above—the focus seems to be on $\mathbb{P}_{X}$. Assuming that the second question above is correct, isn't this the same as saying that

the occurrence of an event $\{\omega\} \in \mathcal{A}$ (i.e., whatever it may mean for a person to occur...) is the same as its probability of being selected to be part of a sample $\{\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}, \omega_{3}, ...\} \subseteq \Omega$?

I hope this makes sense, and I would appreciate any input and intuition.

Simple random sampling determines $\mathbb P.$  $\Omega$ can be considered to be the set of all possible samples of the specified size.  This is about as non-abstract as one can get!  The measure $\mathbb P_X$ on $\mathbb R$ is then determined by whatever random variable $X$ you are studying.

What I understand from your answer is that $\mathbb{P}_{X}$ describes the distribution of $X$, while $\mathbb{P}$ describes the sampling mechanism, which aligns with my intuition! However, I still remain confused about "[...] set of all possible samples of the specified size"—may I ask what you mean here? Or whether you have a resource in mind where I can read about this?

@whuber, ah, I think what you mean is that each sample (e.g., combination of individuals) has an equal probability of being selected in simple random sampling. So, you are abstracting away the individual probabilities to emphasize the selection process at the sample level.

Yes.  And that is a general framework that handles complex sampling methods of all kinds.  A good resource would be Steven Thompson's book, "Sampling."  For more about this perspective see my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/188748/919.

I would like to leave an answer based on my understanding of whuber's comments above.
The interpretation in my question above appears to be correct. As whuber points out, the mechanism of simple random sampling determines $\mathbb{P}$ in the abstract probability measure space. Moreover, it is more general (i.e., perhaps also more attuned to data collection in the social sciences) to think of $\Omega$ as the set of all possible subsets (i.e., samples) of some specified size $n$. This is useful because we can move from probabilities attached to singletons $\{\omega\}$ (i.e., individuals) to probabilities attached to samples $\{\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}, \ldots, \omega_{n}\}$ (i.e., groups of individuals), where $n = 1, 2, \ldots, |\Omega|$.
This means that all samples of size $n$ are equally likely to be selected from $\Omega$, and this is different from saying that all individuals are equally likely to be selected. As whuber points out, considering $\Omega$ as "the set of all possible samples of the specified size" is more general, e.g.:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\}) = \frac{1}{|\Omega|}
    \geq
\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}, \ldots, \omega_{n}\}) = \frac{1}{\binom{|\Omega|}{n}}, \quad 1 \leq n < |\Omega|.
$$
To answer my question directly:

Is simple random sampling an assumption on the probability measure in the abstract probability measure space?

Yes, it is an assumption. The uniformity assumption of $\mathbb{P}$ ensures that the probability distribution measure $\mathbb{P}_{X}$
reflects the true distribution of $X$ in the population $\Omega$ without bias from the sampling mechanism. If $\mathbb{P}$ is not uniform, the pushforward measure $\mathbb{P}_{X}$ will reflect this non-uniformity, leading to a biased distribution of $X$.
I find this bittersweet because while we can never be entirely sure that our assumption about $\mathbb{P}_{X}$ is correct, assuming a uniform $\mathbb{P}$ enables us to assert that if $\mathbb{P}_{X}$ is correctly chosen, it ought to accurately reflect the distribution of $X$ in the population.

Reference
Thompson, S. K. (2012). Sampling (3. ed). Hoboken, NJ: Wiley.

Edit
Simple random sampling is not an assumption, it is a procedure that creates $\mathbb{P}$ (see Thompson, 2012, p. 2). For other subtleties, see the comments to this answer.

Thank you for this ressearch and the summary.  There are some subtleties here, though.  First, in general a sample is an ordered sequence of elements of $\Omega,$ not just a subset.  That's needed in order to handle sampling with replacement.  Consequently, $n$ is not limited to $|\Omega|$ (which may be infinite, btw). The key idea presented in Thompson is that in addition to the probabilities that individual $\omega\in\Omega$ might be in the sample, you often need to consider joint probabilities. Finally, SRS is usually not an assumption: it's a procedure that creates $\mathbb P.$

Thank you for pointing these out! I updated the answer to indicate that SRS is a procedure and to refer the readers to your comment regarding the other subtleties you mentioned.
